# .def files and symbols exports

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, lib

I spent the last 4 hours in the Microsoft docs trying to understand this, since I'm probably misunderstanding the purpose of `.def` files. I am `trying to create a .lib from a .def file`, which will be linked against an executable. So I ran `"lib /def:symbols.def"` in the VS Developer Console, which produced a symbols.lib and a symbols.exp files.

Then I used the generated .lib to link against my executable, however, when I tried to run the executable after linking the lib, it said that

> a "symbols.dll" is missing(?)

but in any moment was mentioned a .dll file to the executable(or was it?), so I opened the symbols.lib in an hex editor and searched for a "symbols.dll", not expecting to find anything, and turns out that for my surprise it found.

Now my question is: why? is this really supposed to happen or am I missing something? what would be, if there is, a workaround for this?

Comment: Did you expect that `lib` tool would somehow magically produce an actual implementation for your functions, from `def` file that only contains their names? What you've generated is an [import library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ehh... Looks like i was confusing import library with static library, since  both have the same extension. Anyway,  thank you for clarifying.